# Angular 2 Reactive Forms trigger validation on submit

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

is there a way that all validators of a reactive forms can be triggered upon submit and not only by the "dirty" and "touch" events?

The reason for this is we have a very large forms which doesn't indicate if a field is required or not, and user might miss some of the required control, so upon submit, it is expected that all of the invalid fields which are missed by the end user will be shown.

I have tried marking the form as "touched" by using the

```
FormGroup.markAsTouched(true);
```

it worked, and so I also tried marking it as "dirty"

```
FormGroup.markAsDirty(true);
```

but the css of the class is still "ng-pristine",

Is there a way to trigger it manually from the component, I tried googling it to no avail, thanks you in advance!

**UPDATE**

I already got it working by iterating the FormGroup.controls and marking it as "dirty", but is there a "standard" way to do this.

Comment: They are always being validated. You should check upon `formGroup.valid` or `formControl.valid`.

Comment: Why not require the form control in the validator?

Comment: hi @HarryNinh, yeah I undestand but what I'm looking for is a way that when you submit the form, all properties with validator must fire so that it will show the user which fields has errors on it.

Comment: hi @JohnBaird, what exactly do you mean? Can you please explain further? Thank you!

Comment: I bet it's the problem with your way of displaying the error. Could you add more snippets?

Comment: hi Harry, my sample is exactly what is found on angular university website. I hace css for **.ng-dirty.ng-invalid** and error templates for each controls which needs validation. What I need is a way to manually trigger the validators of each controls.

Comment: Yea that's the problem. the css class for `.ng-dirty.ng-invalid` is only suitable to certain flow (like their tutorial). You have to modify it to something else. For example, you can define error styling for this selector `.ng-dirty.ng-invalid, .submit-attempt.ng-invalid`, then in your `input`, add `[class.submit-attempt]="submitAttempt"`, and declare the boolean variable `submitAttempt` in your component, turn it to true in your `submit` function.

Comment: hi @HarryNinh, sorry, now I get what you mean, I display errors by checking if the form is dirty, instead I need a bool value that will return true when user click submit and use that as condition.

Comment: Yea that's what I meant :) Happy coding.

Comment: maybe you can put it as an answer so I can upvote for you. :)

Comment: Use the Validators.required on the form control field definition: quantity: ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.numberFieldValidator]],

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This can be achieved with the sample presented **[here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14527#issuecomment-280726674)**, where you can make use of `NgForm` directive:

```html
<form [formGroup]="heroForm" #formDir="ngForm">
```

and then in your validation messages just check if the form is submitted:

```html
<small *ngIf="heroForm.hasError('required', 'formCtrlName') && formDir.submitted">
  Required!
</small>
```

EDIT: Now is also `{ updateOn: 'submit'}` is provided, but that works only if you do not have `required` on the form, as `required` is displayed initially anyway. You can suppress that with checking if field has been touched though.

```ts
// fb is 'FormBuilder'
this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
 // ...
}, { updateOn: 'submit'})
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. No additional code required, works out of the box, no need to programmatically "touch" all the input fields.

Comment: This solution combines the classic template-driven form technique with the new reactive form technique, making it probably unnecessarily inefficient, and confusing because it requires knowledge of both techniques.

Comment: Perfect solution.. :)

Comment: help needed on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534244/form-validation-is-not-working-in-angular @Alex

Comment: How would this work with nested components where you pass in the formgroup to make stuff required?

Answer (score 25):

Coming back after some months, I share here the improved version based on all the comments, just for the record:

```
markAsTouched(group: FormGroup | FormArray) {
  group.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });

  Object.keys(group.controls).map((field) => {
    const control = group.get(field);
    if (control instanceof FormControl) {
      control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
    } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
      this.markAsTouched(control);
    }
  });
}
```

Hope it will be useful!

UPDATE: Angular 8 introduced `FormGroup.markAllAsTouched()` and it does this! :D

Comment: hi thank you for sharing, but I already found the solution as per @Harry Ninh's idea, it's just that he didn't answer it formally. :)

Comment: @arvstracthoughts oh I just saw it, indeed, it makes sense, but I still prefer the shortcut to mark them as dirty because it has no repercusions on my App, but in another one it may be important, so Harry is quite right :)
Now I will mark as dirty only the invalid controls hehe

Comment: @MateoTibaquirá, perhaps you could add `group.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });` on line 2. Just to be sure that all elements including the formGroup itself are touched.

Comment: Marked as touch was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

There are multiple ways to solve the problem. The @Splaktar's answer won't work if you have nested formgroups. So, here's the solution which will work with nested form groups.

> **Solution 1**: Iterate through all formgroups and formcontrols and programmatically touch them to trigger validations.

**Template code:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

**component.ts code:**

```
    onSubmit() {
        if (this.myForm.valid) {
            // save data
        } else {
            this.validateAllFields(this.myForm); 
        }
    }

validateAllFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {         
        Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {  
            const control = formGroup.get(field);            
            if (control instanceof FormControl) {             
                control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
            } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {        
                this.validateAllFields(control);  
            }
        });
    }
```

> **Solution 2**: Use a variable to check if the form has been submitted or not. **FYI:** The submitted field for the ngForm is currently being tested and will be included in future Angular versions. So there will not be a need to create your own variable.

**component.ts code**

```
private formSubmitAttempt: boolean;

onSubmit() {
        this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
        if (this.myForm.valid) {
            console.log('form submitted');
        }
   }
```

**Template code:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">
            Name:
            <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">
        </label>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="myForm.get('name').hasError('required') && formSubmitAttempt">
            Name is required
        </div>
        ...
</form>
```

Comment: hi @Sangram, thank you for the wonderful solution, HarryNinh already suggested the right solution for me, I asked him to post the solution unfortunately, he still doesn't post it.

Comment: hai @Sangram Nandkhile help neede on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534244/form-validation-is-not-working-in-angular

Comment: Hi @Sangram solution 1 is working fine,but it's not validating the FormArray in the formGroup. can you help on this?

Answer (score 5):

This can be accomplished via [`markAsTouched()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markastouched). Until PR [#26812](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/26812) is merged, you can use

```
function markAllAsTouched(group: AbstractControl) {
  group.markAsTouched({onlySelf: true});
  group._forEachChild((control: AbstractControl) => markAllAsTouched(control));
}
```

You can find out more in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.1.x/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L340-L355).

Answer (score 3):

I found something that might be of interest:

On submit I set the `submitAttempt = true` and put this in the div where  validation should take place:

`nickname.touched || nickname.dirty || (nickname.untouched && submitAttempt)`

meaning:
If it hasn't been touched, and we tried to submit, the error shows.

Comment: FormGroupDirective already has a 'submitted' property which can be used.

Answer (score 3):

There is now the updateOn:’submit’ option which will cause validation to trigger on submit, use like:

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({},{updateOn: ‘submit’});
```

Answer (score 2):

My application has many forms and inputs, so I created various custom form components (for normal text inputs, textarea inputs, selects, checkboxes, etc.) so that I don't need to repeat verbose HTML/CSS and form validation UI logic all over the place.

My custom base form component looks up its hosting `FormGroupDirective` and uses its `submitted` property in addition to its `FormControl` states (`valid`, `touched`, etc.) to decide which validation status and message (if any) needs to be shown on the UI.

This solution

- does not require traversing through the form's controls and modifying their status
- does not require adding some additional `submitted` property to each control
- does not require any additional form validation handling in the `ngSubmit`-binded `onSubmit` methods
- does not combine template-driven forms with reactive forms

**form-base.component:**

```
import {Host, Input, OnInit, SkipSelf} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroupDirective} from '@angular/forms';


export abstract class FormBaseComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() label: string;
  formControl: FormControl;

  constructor(@Host() @SkipSelf()
              private formControlHost: FormGroupDirective) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const form = this.formControlHost.form;
    this.formControl = <FormControl>form.controls[this.id];
    if (!this.formControl) {
      throw new Error('FormControl \'' + this.id + '\' needs to be defined');
    }
  }

  get errorMessage(): string {
    // TODO return error message based on 'this.formControl.errors'
    return null;
  }

  get showInputValid(): boolean {
    return this.formControl.valid && (this.formControl.touched || this.formControlHost.submitted);
  }

  get showInputInvalid(): boolean {
    return this.formControl.invalid && (this.formControl.touched || this.formControlHost.submitted);
  }
}
```

**form-text.component:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBaseComponent} from '../form-base.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'yourappprefix-form-text',
  templateUrl: './form-text.component.html'
})
export class FormTextComponent extends FormBaseComponent {

}
```

**form-text.component.html:**

```
<label class="x_label" for="{{id}}">{{label}}</label>
<div class="x_input-container"
     [class.x_input--valid]="showInputValid"
     [class.x_input--invalid]="showInputInvalid">
  <input class="x_input" id="{{id}}" type="text" [formControl]="formControl">
  <span class="x_input--error-message" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</span>
</div>
```

**Usage:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
  <yourappprefix-form-text id="someField" label="Some Field"></yourappprefix-form-text>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

"dirty", "touched", "submitted" could be combined using next method:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="doSomething()" #ngForm="ngForm">
<input type="text" placeholder="Put some text" formControlName="textField" required>
<div *ngIf="textField.invalid && (textField.dirty || textField.touched || ngForm.submitted)">
  <div *ngIf="textField.errors.required">Required!</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is the cleanest approach in terms of getting a reference to the 'submitted' value and is still valid using angular 15.

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you are asking for. You only want to update validation messages on each submit. The best way to do this is storing the history of the control state.

```
export interface IValdiationField {
  submittedCount: number;
  valid: boolean;
}
class Component {
   // validation state management
   validationState: Map<string, IValdiationField | number> = new Map();

   constructor() {
      this.validationState.set('submitCount', 0);
   }

   validationChecker(formControlName: string): boolean {

    // get submitted count
    const submittedCount: number = (this.validationState.get('submitCount') || 0) as number;

    // form shouldn't show validation if form not submitted
    if (submittedCount === 0) {
       return true;
    }

    // get the validation state
    const state: IValdiationField = this.validationState.get(formControlName) as IValdiationField;

    // set state if undefined or state submitted count doesn't match submitted count
    if (state === undefined || state.submittedCount !== submittedCount) {
       this.validationState.set(formControlName, { submittedCount, valid: this.form.get(formControlName).valid } );
       return this.form.get(formControlName).valid;
     }

        // get validation value from validation state managment
       return state.valid;
   }
   submit() {
     this.validationState.set('submitCount', (this.validationState.get('submitCount') as number) + 1);
   } 
}
```

Then in the html code  *ngIf="!validationChecker('formControlName')" to show error message.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the out-of-the-box validators, the best approach is simply to check whether the form group is valid when the user hits submit.

`markAllAsTouched()` can then be used to trigger a validity check on each field of the form:

[Stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2lvwr?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.ts).

```
// Component

loginForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
        username: new FormControl(null, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(4)
        ]),
        password: new FormControl(null, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(4)
        ]),
    });
}

submitLoginForm() {
    if (!this.loginForm.invalid) { // Checks form input validity
        // Form input is valid
        console.log('Valid login attempt - allow submission');
    } else {
        // Form input is not valid
        this.loginForm.markAllAsTouched(); // Trigger validation across form
        console.log('Invalid login attempt - block submission');
    }
}

// Template

<form id="login_wrapper" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="submitLoginForm()">
    <h1>Log in</h1>
    <mat-form-field color="accent">
        <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
        <input matInput
            placeholder="Username"
            type="text"
            formControlName="username">
        <mat-error
            *ngIf="loginForm.controls.username.invalid && (loginForm.controls.username.dirty || loginForm.controls.username.touched)">
            Please enter a valid username
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field color="accent">
        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
        <input matInput
            placeholder="Password"
            type="password"
            formControlName="password">
        <mat-error
            *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.invalid && (loginForm.controls.password.dirty || loginForm.controls.password.touched)">
            Please enter a valid password
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button id="login_btn"
        mat-flat-button
        color="primary"
        type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes:

- you do not want to add ngForm just to know if the controller has been submitted
- you want to know if any controller belongs to a submitted form i.e. has a submitted ancestor.

With the functions below you can flag any `Control` as submitted (`FormControl`, `FormGroup`, `ArrayGroup`) and check if the `Control` is or has a submitted parent.

```js
import { AbstractControl as AngularAbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

const isSubmittedSymbol = Symbol('This control is flagged as submitted');

/**
 * Return true if the form control or it's parent has been flagged as submitted
 */
export function isSubmitted(control: AngularAbstractControl): boolean {
  if (control.parent) {
    return isSubmitted(control.parent);
  }
  return !!control[isSubmittedSymbol];
}

/**
 * Flag the form control
 */
export function setSubmitted(control: AngularAbstractControl, submitted: boolean = true) {
  control[isSubmittedSymbol] = submitted;
}
```

dummy example:

```js
public onSubmit(){
 submitted(this.myFormGroup);
 // your logic
}

public onReset(){
 submitted(this.myFormGroup, false);
}

public isSubmitted(){
 isSubmitted(this.myFormGroup);
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
        your form logic here
</form>
<button (click)="onSubmit()"
        [disabled]=isSubmitted()>
</button>
```

Note: As the `isSubmitted()` function recursively checks if the parent is submitted you can of course use it for a `FormControl` within a `FormArray` within a `FormGroup` (or any configuration). As long as the root parent will be flagged as isSubmitted, all the children will be virtually flagged as the same.