# Check if FormGroup has been submitted

Tags: angular

In template-driven form, we can check that with the `submitted` property from `NgForm`. But how to achieve that in Model-driven form?

Comment: You can [use this to "Flag a FormGroup as submitted"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69434570/532695)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I just found out you can use `ngForm` together with `formGroup`:

```
<form [formGroup]='form' #ngForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)='validation(ngForm)' 
  [ngClass]="{ 'form-unsubmitted': !ngForm.submitted}">
```

Answer (score 10):

Create one variable `IsSubmitted = false` into component.
Once submit a button you can set it true into `onSubmit()` function.
**for example :**

```
onSubmit(): void{
     this.isSubmited = true;
  // code....
}
```

set it again to false after response

Comment: sure, i was just wondering if there is a Angular2's way of doing it :)

Comment: see here https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol