# Validate, that user touched each input

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

When validating a form, you can check, if a user has touched an input, checkbox etc. (`X.touched`). Is there a build in validator, that a user must touch each input at least once (tab over it etc).

Background: I have a form with checkboxes , where the user has to validate that the input is correct. Since checkboxes can have only two states, I init them with false, however I want the user to check them at least once

Comment: you mean that you don't need that all checkbox don't need to be checked but all need to be touched?

Comment: exactly, and I think it can be done via a own directive also...

Comment: You can use form group. Put all field in the group and then using map check touched element or not. In this example they make all field touched. But you can see there how to check all field and do similar but with the touched condition. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743406/6474811

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<form name="form" role="form" class="form-horizontal" novalidate #form="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Checkbox Label</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 checkbox">
            <label class="i-checks">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxLabel" id="checkboxLabel" [(ngModel)]="checkboxLabel"><i></i>
            </label>
            <div [hidden]="form.controls.checkboxLabel?.touched">
                Checkbox not touched
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Well since my checkboxes are created with a foreach statement, this is not really a option for me...

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a parallel array (with all values set to false) next to the one used to create the checkboxes, having the same size also. Each time a checkbox is changed, change that array values to true. Then add listener to form changes:

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;
myForm: NgForm;
....
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((value: any) => {
         console.log("One of the checkbox was touched");
         // here check if the all values of array are true
    });
}
```

Not the 'smartest' solution, but will work

Comment: @Roma Skydan The tag is angular and I see angularjs nowhere in the post...