# Angular 5 - Reactive forms doesn't validate form on submit

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular5

I have a simple form as below:

**some.component.html**

```
<form class="example-form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="testform">
     <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" required/>
     <app-show-errors [control]="claimform.controls.name"></app-show-errors>
     <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Next</button>
</form>
```

**some.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.testform= new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', { validators: Validators.required})
    }, {updateOn: 'submit'});
}

onSubmit() {
    if (this.testform.valid) {
      alert('saving data');
    } else {
      this._validationService.validateAllFormFields(this.testform);
    }
}
```

**validationService.ts**

```
validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
      const control = formGroup.get(field);
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
      } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
        this.validateAllFormFields(control);
      }
    });
}
```

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893430/angular-2-reactive-forms-trigger-validation-on-submit)**

---

**Problem**

The form will **[validate on submit](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14527)** if left blank, but even after filling the value when I check `this.testform.valid` it returns **`false`**. But if I remove `updateOn:'submit'` on `form` then it validates on `blur` of input control and when value is entered it validates form return `true`. Not sure if `updateOn` is working fine or not or whether I've implemented this in a proper way. Could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your HTML you have two calls to `onSubmit()` function, from submit button:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Next</button>
```

and from the form:

```
<form class="example-form" 
      ovalidate 
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" 
      autocomplete="off" 
      [formGroup]="testform">
```

The first call to be triggered is the button's trigger, which actually does nothing in terms of updating your reactive form, since you set `FormGroup`'s option to `{updateOn: 'submit'}`. The second call to be triggered is the form's trigger, which does actual form update.

Here is `FormGroup` directive config:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[formGroup]',
  providers: [formDirectiveProvider],
  host: {'(submit)': 'onSubmit($event)', '(reset)': 'onReset()'},
  exportAs: 'ngForm'
})
```

as we can see in [`host`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.1.0/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts#L64) property DOM form's submit (triggered by hitting ENTER while focused within form or clicking form's submit button) will call [`onSubmit()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.1.0/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts#L135) function:

```
onSubmit($event: Event): boolean {
  (this as{submitted: boolean}).submitted = true;
  syncPendingControls(this.form, this.directives);
  this.ngSubmit.emit($event);
  return false;
}
```

which then will call [`syncPendingControls()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.1.0/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L172) function:

```
export function syncPendingControls(form: FormGroup, directives: NgControl[]): void {
  form._syncPendingControls();
  directives.forEach(dir => {
    const control = dir.control as FormControl;
    if (control.updateOn === 'submit' && control._pendingChange) {
      dir.viewToModelUpdate(control._pendingValue);
      control._pendingChange = false;
    }
  });
}
```

which updates a model at last.

So, in your case, just remove `(click)="onSubmit()"` from the submit button:

```
<button type="submit">Next</button>
```

also you do not need `required` DOM element property on your input, since you set it using Reactive Forms API `validators: Validators.required` and since you set your form to `novalidate` which cancels HTML5 form validation.