# How to make an angular custom validator work only on submission?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, authentication, angular-reactive-forms

I developed a login component using the Angular-8 **reactive form** concept. I have asynchronous validations like empty fields, invalid emails. these validations should be asynchronous. But I have two custom validators like **is-user-exist**, **is-password-match-user**. These two validators should be only validated if user clicks submit. How to have a reactive form validator to **check these two validators alone on submitting** and other validations asynchronously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Reactive Forms trigger validation on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893430/angular-2-reactive-forms-trigger-validation-on-submit)

Comment: Thanks, but the below answer helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control for a form (or single form elements) when the value or the validity is updated. This feature has been available in AngularJS 1.x but missed in Angular 2+ from some time. Starting from some version (Angular 5 I think) can be one of:

- **change**: change is the default mode. By using this update option the form / form control is updated after every single change.
- **blur**: the blur change mode is only updated the from values / validity status after a form control lost the focus.
- **submit**: updates are only done after form submit.

In reactive forms this can be done with the setting `updateOn` of either form or form control. Sample code:

```
this.nameForm = new FormGroup ({
  firstname: new FormControl('', {
    validators: Validators.required,
    updateOn: 'change'
  }),
  lastname: new FormControl('', {
    validators: Validators.required,
    updateOn: 'submit' // <--
  })
});
```